# MySQL query to find related rows from single table

Tags: mysql

I have a table structure as attached [image: News] in MySQL Database.

The problem is for id=1, I have tags like AI,BOTS in tag column. So when I query with id=1, I need to fetch all the rows which contain either AI or BOTS. So the output will be rows with id=1, id=3 and id=4.
Similarly, if i query with id=4, I should get rows 1 and 4.

I tried query

```
Select * From news where tags in (select tags from news where id=1);
```

but it didnt help.
I don`t have much expertise in writing too complex database queries, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Storing values as  CSV is very bad database design.

Comment: Actual values are in db, I just copied to excel to minimise the db columns and sake of simplicity

Comment: i think, the data aren't stored in a `csv-file`. This should just represent the data easier, than watching it in MySQL

Comment: Please post ur table structure

Comment: I think, this question will be answered by this: [Where field contains A or B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121630/how-to-write-mysql-query-where-a-contains-a-or-b)

Comment: @SacrumDeus yes true

Comment: @RajendraGupta Check this link out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121630/how-to-write-mysql-query-where-a-contains-a-or-b)

Comment: @SacrumDeus We know that is not a CSV file. But what i say  CSV DATA in a column of a table is very bad

Comment: @SacrumDeus let me check

Comment: @SacrumDeus select * from news where tags LIKE(select tags from news where id=1); will o/p only first row

Comment: @RajendraGupta You can do `select * from news where id = 1 and (tags = 'AI' or tags = 'BOTS');` I think, this should work

Comment: @SacrumDeus where id=1 will only give row with id =1 but i also need other rows where tags="AI" or tags="BOTS"

Comment: for this reason i add the query ` where id = 1 and (tags = 'AI' or tags = 'BOTS');`

Answer (score 1):

create a new function name with find_in_set_extra

```
BEGIN
DECLARE limitCount INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE res INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE temp TEXT;
SET limitCount = 1 + LENGTH(inputList) - LENGTH(REPLACE(inputList, ',',''));
simple_loop:LOOP
SET counter = counter + 1;
SET temp = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(inputList,',',counter),',',-1);
SET res = FIND_IN_SET(temp,targetList);
IF res > 0 THEN LEAVE simple_loop; END IF;
IF counter = limitCount THEN LEAVE simple_loop; END IF;
END LOOP simple_loop;
RETURN res;
END<
```

using this function you can find data like

```
find_in_set_extra('a,b,c','b,c')
```